# save contents of excel file before reading it using poi

Tags: java, excel, user-interface, apache-poi

I am making an application that created 2 new spreadsheet files. The idea is for the user to enter data into this excel files and make program read it. However the problem is that, after the data has been entered and saved (pressing the save icon in excel) the program just does not see this data,it  remains as if nothing was entered there. What I need is somehow to save it programmicaly using poi. Any suggestions?

Here is the code:

my gui class:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{

private Panel buttonHolder;
private Button crossReference;
private Button generateHPD;
private CrossReference ref = null;
private XSSFWorkbook log;
private XSSFWorkbook sheet;
private XSSFSheet logSheet;
private XSSFSheet sSheet;

public GUI () throws Exception{
    this.setTitle("NYWM Cross Reference Application");
    this.setSize(400,100);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    buttonHolder = new Panel (new BorderLayout());
    this.add(buttonHolder);

    crossReference = new Button ("CrossReference");
    generateHPD = new Button ("Generate HPD");

    buttonHolder.add(crossReference, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    buttonHolder.add(generateHPD, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    logSheet =  createExcelSheet ("D:/Log.xlsx", "Log");
    sSheet =    createExcelSheet("D:/Spreadsheet.xlsx", "Spreadsheet");

    crossReference.addActionListener(new crossReferenceButtonListener());
    generateHPD.addActionListener(new generateHPDButtonListener());
}



public XSSFSheet getLogSheet() {
    return logSheet;
}



public XSSFSheet getsSheet() {
    return sSheet;
}



private XSSFSheet createExcelSheet (String path, String fileName) throws Exception{
    try{
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream (path);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook ();
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(fileName);
    wb.write(out);

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "rundll32 url.dll, FileProtocolHandler " + path);

    return sheet;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
}

private class crossReferenceButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){

        try { 
            XSSFSheet sSheet = getsSheet();
            XSSFSheet logSheet = getLogSheet();

            ref = new CrossReference();
            //ref = new CrossReference (log.getSheetAt(0), sheet.getSheetAt(0));
            ref.CrossReferenceCont(logSheet, sSheet);


            ref.CrossRef();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cross Reference was successful!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

CrossReferenceCont method

```
public void CrossReferenceCont(XSSFSheet wsLog, XSSFSheet wsSheet)
        throws Exception {

    log = new PropertyList(wsLog);
    sheet = new PropertyList(wsSheet);

    logArray = log.getPropertyList();
    sheetArray = log.getPropertyList();
}
```

property list method:

```
public PropertyList(XSSFSheet ws) throws Exception{

    try{
        //File excel = new File (excelFilePath);
        //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (excel);
    //  XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);


        int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println ("Number of rows is " + rowNum);
        propertyList = new ArrayList <Property>(rowNum);

        for (int i = 0; i <= rowNum; i++){
            property  = new Property (ws, i);

            propertyList.add(new Property(property));

        }
```

and finaly the property method: here where program crashes

```
public Property(XSSFSheet sheet, int row) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Cell cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(0); //crashes here, nullPointer

    int type = cell.getCellType();

    //setting the address-------------------------------------------------
    if (type == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
        address = cell.getStringCellValue();
    } else if (type == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
        int addressTemp = (int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
        address = String.valueOf(addressTemp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly. Does this solve your problem

i < rowNum

Comment: this would only help to avoid excepation. but the actual problem is that i need java to be able to read the rows that i entered. java creates a new empty excel file (has nothing in it). user enters data into the file and saves and presses the button "Cross Reference" but java does not see any data in the file (even thou it was entered) so the question is how to make java see this data. how do i save it properly???

Comment: Are you writing to the stream after cross reference? Kind of wb.write(out);

Comment: no i write when i create the workbook (it is viewed in r the code), after the book was written i enter the contents but program doesnt see them

Comment: If you are saving the data using your program you have to write it again. If you are doing it manually, you need to read the input stream again using the file path.

Comment: can you help me with a code here... i tried to write using workBookname.write(out) after i saved it but it wont work

Comment: for that I need to understand the flow.. can you also paste your main class (or the part of code which calls the above methods)

Comment: there is the whole flow. Main class has nothing except calling the GUI. GUI writes a gui that has 2 buttons "Cross Reference" and "Generate HPD" , GUI contractor creates and opens 2 spreadsheets where I copypaste data and press "Cross Reference" pressing this button calls the crossReferenceButtonListener that creates a reference to CrossReference class. CrossReference class instantiates a PropertyList class that has the ArrayList and one by one suppose to create a new Property by reading data from the excel sheet. the code shows the entire flow

Comment: I feel your code is reading and writing to two different instances. Added another answer. Hope that will help !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getSheet(), make a getFilePath(). Then get the worksheet using that path.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(FileUtils.openInputStream(file));
Sheet templateSheet = templateWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

Comment: If you have a File object, then [open the workbook directly from that](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)! As explained in the [POI docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), using a File is lower memory than going via an InputStream